# Latex - undefined control sequence \sym

Tags: latex

I cannot compile a latex document because I get the error "! Undefined control sequence. xvari & -0.0901\sym", but I do not understand what is gonig on. I suspect it should be a pretty easy fix but I have not managed to fix it / find the answer online so far. Would really appreciate if someone could take a look.

Below is my code, thank you very much!

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,url,changepage,amsmath,bm,float,subfig}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\Rom}[1]
    {\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Eq. 1}\\
\hline
xvari       &     -0.0824         \\
            &    (0.0601)         \\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Eq. 2}\\
\hline
xvari       &     -0.0901\sym{**} \\
            &    (0.0370)         \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the error by defining `\sym`. Replace the definition below with whatever you want the macro to do.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,url,changepage,amsmath,bm,float,subfig}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\Rom}[1]
    {\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
    
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Eq. 1}\\
\hline
xvari       &     -0.0824         \\
            &    (0.0601)         \\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Eq. 2}\\
\hline
xvari       &     -0.0901\sym{**} \\
            &    (0.0370)         \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! the \sym{} code appears automatically when I generate the table with Stata. I just want it to look like the two asterisks, how should I tell that to Latex?

Comment: I does look like two asterisks, doesn't it?

Comment: yes indeed apologies, thank you!